# Finding the column space of Khatri-Rao product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us denote the Khatri-Rao product by $\odot$.

I want to find the column space of the matrix $H \odot H$, which I know has full column rank.
The information is have is

- the column space of $H$,
- $c = (H \odot H) \cdot v$, in which $c$ and $v$ are known vectors.

Is it even possible to find the column space of $H \odot H$ with this information?
(I wanted to check this by determining how many unknows and equations I have, but I'm not sure how to deal with 'subspace' knowledge in this matter.)

Thanks in advance